# Problem with ViewData and ViewBag in ASPNET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, viewstate, razor-pages

I have a problem with ViewData and ViewBag in ASP.NET Core.
This is my portion of controller code :

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["item.CustomerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers, "CustomerId", "CustomerId");
        AddressesBackOfficeCreateViewModel model = new AddressesBackOfficeCreateViewModel();
        model.item = new Addresses();
        return View(model);
    }
```

and this one of the cshtml code

```
     <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="item.CustomerId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="item.CustomerId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CustomerId"></select>
     </div>
```

The problem is that the customer dropdown list is empty.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're adding a key of `item.CustomerId` but then trying to access just `CustomerId` in the View.

Comment: Oh my god ..... Thanks a lot